# Check response from an AT command to send an SMS using a modem

Tags: php, serial-port, sms, at-command

I want to ask about the `AT` command. I can successfully send an SMS through the modem, but I don't know when I get response from the modem. So if I send multiple SMS messages and got an error for one of them, there will be more of a delay than normal.

How can I get response from a single `AT` command within the timeframe of my 5 second delay (the sleep call in my code).

```
ser_write("AT+CMGS=\"".$data."\" \r\n b");
ser_write($head." \r\n");
ser_write($isi." \x1a\" ") ;
sleep(5); // wait a while
$str = ser_read();
```

Comment: Don't you have the possibility to use another language? PHP is not really the best language for this, especially because it's not event-driven.

Comment: sry, it's embedded in another application. so it's only use php or javascript or jquery,,,

Comment: You can use javascript. Javascript is event-driven. I would apply for javascript instead of PHP: you can listen to the read event instead of sleeping.

Comment: any link/source for javascript?
thanks

Comment: Use this library for example: https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport

Comment: @Blaatpraat I don't think that will work.  If he is limited to php, javascript and jquery then I don't think node.js is a valid option.  He would have to spawn out a system call to execute node.js.  If he can do that, then there is no language limitation and python, java, and C are just as valid options.